# Swift integrated XWebView project now want create iPA file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, wkwebview, xwebview

I am working with XWebView framework in my swift project where I am passing a native object to javascript
I have successfully integrated XWebView framework in my project.
But when I create an IPA, the organiser window shows 2 different options - one is my project and the other is XWebView framework
Code is working fine on simulators and device but IPA is not working.

XWebView framework: https://github.com/XWebView/XWebView

Below is the attached screenshot of my organiser window
Any help would be appreciated regarding XWebView or how could create a working IPA
Thanks in advance
[archive organizer ipa screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxa49.png)

Comment: Solved. Now using cocpods : https://cocoapods.org/pods/XWebView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed using cocoapods: cocoapods.org/pods/XWebView
Managed dependencies using **cocoapods**.